# Month wise display

Tags: sql-server

```
Start Date: (mm/dd/yyyy) 05/09/2007
End Date: (mm/dd/yyyy) 08/20/2007
```

While giving the start date and end date using the above values, need to display the report like the following format.

**Notes:** Need Single query

```
Start Date End Date
05/09/2007 05/31/2007
06/01/2007 06/30/2007
07/01/2007 07/31/2007
08/01/2007 08/20/2007
```

Please help me with this query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try something like this using Sql Server 2005

```
DECLARE @StartDate DATETIME,
        @EndDate DATETIME

SELECT  @StartDate = '09 May 2009',
        @EndDate = '20 Aug 2009'

;WITH CTE AS(
        SELECT  @StartDate StartDate,
                DATEADD(MM, 1, CAST('01 ' + DATENAME(mm, @StartDate) +' ' + CAST(DATEPART(yyyy, @StartDate) AS VARCHAR(4)) AS DATETIME)) - 1 EndDate 
        UNION ALL
        SELECT  EndDate + 1 StartDate,
                CASE WHEN DATEADD(MM, 1, EndDate + 1) - 1 > @EndDate THEN @EndDate ELSE DATEADD(MM, 1, EndDate + 1) - 1 END EndDate
        FROM    CTE
        WHERE   EndDate < @EndDate
)
SELECT  *
FROM    CTE
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the [page with SQL Server datetime formats](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174450.aspx).  You could use it like:

```
select 
    convert(varchar(32), StartDate, 101) as StartDate
,   convert(varchar(32), EndDate, 101) as EndDate
,   ...
from YourTable
where StartDate between '2007-09-05' and '2007-08-20'
or EndDate between '2007-09-05' and '2007-08-20'
```

To display rows that end or start in that timeframe.

If you'd like to enter dates in the "month-day-year" format, but your SQL Server is confiugred to use something else, you can use `set dateformat`.  This allows you to change the setting for your session only.  For `dmy`, this works like:

```
set dateformat 'mdy'
select cast('12/31/2009' as datetime)
```